# Objects Evade or Repell eachother in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

I'm trying to achieve this. Sphere's displacing the position of other objects as they move through them. Sorta like someone pushing through a crowd.

[image: Repel or Evade]

I've managed to get this far in AN but adding more than one effector is where I'm getting stuck.

[image]

[image: Node setup]

It was easy enough to displace the arrows based on an effector but I couldn't get them to choose the most efficient direction to travel. That is why I made them point towards the effector so they could be pushed back on their local X-axis. This adds complexity to the setup that I can't solve now that I need the arrows to "point" to more than one Effector.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

I divide this **Repeller Effect** into parts:

1. Offsetting the locations with multiple-object effectors.
2. Changing the direction of arrows with respect to the effectors'
   location.

**Part-1:** Idea is, we offset the locations (grid-points) using the first effector then use those offsetted grid-points for next the effector with the help of **reinitializing option** of the loop node.

We want to offset location using more than one effectors (I'm using empties objects), so we need the Loop-Node and looping over effectors to get the location of each effector.
[image]

Then I have added the Vector-list (name it as grid-points) as "new parameter" in the Loop-Node and calculated the offset by taking the difference between the effector's location and grid-points using Vector-Node which I use as offset-list for the Offset-Node to repel the grid-points based on the Object-Falloff,
[image]

Now, select the Loop-Node then open the N-panel and reinitialize the grid-points and also enable the *output* option so that we can use these grid-points for instanced objects *which are arrows in this case but you can use any object*. Here is the complete setup for this part:
[image]

**Part-2:** To calculate the direction for the arrows, I take the difference of effector's location and offsetted grid-points. Now, to get the effect that arrows point toward the effector based on the distance from the effector (e.g. like in case of [electric field](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/charges-and-fields/latest/charges-and-fields_en.html)), so we have to normalize directions w.r.t inverse of distances using Math-Node. You can also change the direction of arrows (i.e. point away or toward the effector) by changing the **1** to **-1** in the Math-Node.
[image]

Next, we add these normalized directions for all effectors which we can do that by creating an empty Vector-list from "new parameter" then reinitializing it and enable the *output* option for further use in the N-panel,
[image]

From the outputs of Loop-Node, first, normalize the directions to one then connect them to Direction-To-Rotation node, and then to the Object-Transforms-Output Node,
[image]

**The complete Node-Tree** (*I have added the Switch-Node to change arrow direction*):
[image]

**Note:- This Node-Tree also works for 3DGrid-Points.**

Comment: Wow, @3DsinghVFX you are amazing. There is a lot here I didn't know. Thank you.

Comment: can you please share the project file . Apparently i can't able to get grid points in invoke subprogram node (shown in image 1) in blender 4.0 . I will thankfull paji. Madi mdad kardo.