# Want to create Electric field visualization using arrows and charge with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, animation-nodes

I want to create the electric field image visualisation in blender geometry nodes but i have no idea how to make them. Can anyone guide me how to solve this ?
[image: Electric Field Visualisation]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149405/objects-evade-or-repell-eachother-in-animation-nodes/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/288968/can-one-emulate-the-shape-of-repulsive-magnetic-fields-from-two-like-charges-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be the following:

[image]

Use two empty to represent the charge locations, and add parameters for the charge values.

Define a grid and instanciate an arrow on its points.

Align the arrows to the force field of the two charges.

The force field of a charge is the following node group:

[image]

Which calculate the force with the charge value and its magnitude relative to `1 / distance²` of the charge.

[image] (Blender 4.0)

Comment: Thank you so much sir